# Trying to Install SASS

Tags: ruby, sass

**Goal:** successfully install Sass

**Problem:**

```
gem install sass
```

**returns:**

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Everything I did that led up to this:

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

Download the tarball

```
tar -xzf ruby-2.4.0.tar.gz

mv ruby-2.4.0 /opt/

./configure

make

make install
```

and then I get my error. Not sure what I did wrong.

I just tried

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

and got the same error when trying to install sass.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install ruby-sass
```

Works perfectly.